# Is it possible to color format string comparisons inside of a Mox expectation?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

when a string equality assertion fails in an ExUnit test case, a color-formatted output is provided. Eg., for:

```
test "my test" do
 assert "xyz" == "xwz"
end
```

we get

[image]

But when I do it inside of [expect/4](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html#expect/4):

```
test "my test" do
  expect(MyMock, :post, fn data ->
    assert "xyz" == "xwz"
  end)
end
```

no formatting is done, though:

[image]

Any idea if if there's a way to get the same formatting done inside of expect?

PS: What I really want is a way to get a nice string diff when I compare two long strings. Any alternatives are welcome.

PS2: Using mox 1.0.2 on OSX

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, starting with your example code, but I get the correct colouring for both. Something's missing from your question.

Comment: I tried as well, everything is colorized as expected. Please share your env, `mox` version, OS.

Comment: Using mox 1.0.2 on OSX, elixir 1.14.1

Answer (score -3):

If you are doing string comparisons on errors, I would suggest you avoid ANSI color codes altogether because they add a lot of "noise" to the output.  ANSI color codes are optional anyhow because they are not supported on every system.

In your `config/text.exs` (or in which-ever environment you need to work with), add the following to disable the ANSI formatting:

```
config :elixir, :ansi_enabled, false
```

See the corresponding docs for [IO.ANSI.enabled?/0](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/IO.ANSI.html#enabled?/0)